# Eigenvalue eigenvector extraction routine

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, eigen, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I need to extract the lowest, e.g., 30 eigenvalues and their eigenvectors from a real symmetric sparse double-precision matrix which has a size about 200k x 200k. I know it's huge (about 310 GB if they are 8-byte doubles) but I have enough RAM for it. A full diagonalization is insane. Would you please point me to any packages/libraries that does a decent eigenvalue/eigenvector extraction? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Seeking for library recommendations is off-topic on SO. Maybe [math.se] can give you pointers on what kind of algorithm to use.

Comment: I would suggest [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: http://slepc.upv.es